# Problem in evaluating this limit using Taylor series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

If one says:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}-4}{5x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{2x}}{5x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+2x+\frac{4x^{2}}{2}+\frac{8x^{3}}{6}+\cdots}{5x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{8x^{3}}{6}}{5x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{8x^{3}}{30x^{2}}=\infty$

The answer to the limit is correct, but is there a mathematical problem to use Taylor series at 0 as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Indeed "there is a mathematical problem". Put more bluntly, this "proof" is just absurd.

Comment: There is no problem if you use the series properly, for example by saying that for all positive $x$, we have $e^{2x}\gt \frac{(2x)^3}{3!}$, and therefore our numerator is $\gt \frac{8x^3}{6}-5$.  But you did not use the series properly.

Comment: @André Nicolas: So if I were to put that statement (for all positive x,...) would it solve the problem? How can I use the series expansion as x approaches infinity?

Comment: The series expansion of $e^x$ is valid for all $x$. So we can use it to derive the inequality of my comment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. There are marginally different Taylor series way. For example, using **all** the terms up to the $x^3$ term,  we can see that if $x\gt 1$ then the top is $\gt \frac{8x^3}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky to have a series with positive coefficients, considered for positive values of $x$. This leads to a simple lower bound for $f$: just drop  all terms except one. The best part is that you get to choose which term to keep.  Let's state the result in greater generality:

**Claim**. *Suppose that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ is a function whose Taylor series at some point $a\in\mathbb R$ converges on $\mathbb R$ and has nonnegative coefficients. Then $f$ is either a polynomial, or it grows at $+\infty$ faster than any polynomial:* 
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} = \infty \qquad \forall n\in\mathbb N \tag{1}$$

**Proof**.   Suppose $f$ is not a polynomial. Given $n$, choose $m>n$ such that the $m$th degree term in the Taylor series of $f$ is nonzero, i.e., $c_m>0$. By the nonnegativity assumption, $f(x)\ge c_m(x-a)^m$ for all $x\ge a$. Since
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{c_m(x-a)^m}{x^n} = \infty  $$ 
(1) follows. $\quad\Box$

---

If your series had terms of varying sign, trying to use it as $x\to \infty$ would likely be   painful.